# Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Tags: ionic-framework, gradle, ionic3, ionic4

I have two project with Ionic 3 and 4 and whenever I run `ionic cordova run android` it always gets stuck at `Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details`.

When running `gradle --status` nothing happens but the output:

> IDLE

I updated nodejs, gradle, java/jdk and other paths but still same situation.
for iOS everything works perfectly.

Here is my Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.15
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.1, (and 14 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/chaouimar1/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.10.0
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v12.14.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.13.7
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504
```

Answer (score 0):

use gradle --status command To get a list of running Gradle Daemons
use gridle --stop to stop gradle daemons or in your gradle.properties
add this :
org.gradle.daemon=false

Comment: gradle --status always give the output 'No Gradle daemons are running.', and changing org.gradle.daemon to false in ./platforms/android/gradle.properties doesn't work either :/

Answer (score 0):

Running `cordova clean` fixed this issue for me